# Getting null values from manually created cardview inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to collect data from all the cardviews available inside recyclerView and send the data list to server using rest api.
Each cardView contains edittext, datepicker & spinner. So, i want to get the data from all the cards and store that data in a list. I tried doing that using the following code but the problem that i am facing is that when i click on add button which is present on each card, a new card is created below that card but when i try to fetch the data stored in that newly added card i am getting null values. So, please help me to fetch data from all the cardviews present inside recyclerview and store them in a list and use that list in save method.

**EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.java**

```
package abc.com.abcpos.forms;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import abc.com.abcpos.Adapters.EducationInfoAdapter;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.SavingUrls;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.Validations;
import abc.com.abcpos.Handlers.HttpHandler;
import abc.com.abcpos.MainActivity;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpEducationDetailsModel;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpPersonalDetails;
import abc.com.abcpos.R;
import abc.com.abcpos.WelcomeActivity;

public class EmpEducationInfoFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    boolean connected=false;
    String jsonStr;
    NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod numKeyBoard;
    EmpEducationDetailsModel empEducationDetailsModelObject;
    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationDetailsModelLists;
    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> saveEducationDetailsModelLists;
    private RecyclerView empEducationDetailsRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter empEducationDetailsAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager empEducationDetailsLayoutManager;
    Button saveBtn,cancelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emp_education_info_form);
        initViews();
        initListeners();

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED||                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
            connected=true;
        }else{
            connected=false;
        }

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarEmpEducationInfoFormActivity);
        toolbar.setTitle("Education Details");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarTitle));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        saveBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        cancelBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        numKeyBoard=new NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod();

        empEducationDetailsModelLists=new ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>();

        empEducationDetailsRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_EducationDetailsActivity);
        empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    private void initListeners(){

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveEducationDetailsModelLists.get(1).getUniversity();
                /*Sender s = new Sender(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this, SavingUrls.sending_edu_det_url);
                s.execute();*/
                //checkValidation();
                /*Intent i = new Intent(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("submitFlags", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("educationInfoFlag", true);
                prefsEditor.commit();
                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;

        }
    }

    public void sendAllDataToServer(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList) {
        saveEducationDetailsModelLists=mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            try{
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
                String url = "http://202.38.173.190:8080/TelephoneDirectoryApi/getAllCategoryData";
                Date date = new Date();

                if (connected) {
                    /*jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);*/
                    jsonStr="[{\"userId\":\"kbg-000002\",\"education\":\"Graduation\",\"university\":\"sdsa\",\"marks\":\"321\",\"passingYear\":\"3232\"," +
                            "\"stream\":\"dsdsa\",\"grade\":\"d\",\"empEducationList\":null},{\"userId\":\"kbg-000002\",\"education\":\"Post Graduation\"," +
                            "\"university\":\"sdsa\",\"marks\":\"321\",\"passingYear\":\"3232\",\"stream\":\"dsdsa\",\"grade\":\"d\",\"empEducationList\":null}]";

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {
                            ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationList = new ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>();
                            JSONArray eduArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                            for (int i = 0; i < eduArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = eduArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String userId = jsonobject.getString("userId");
                                String education = jsonobject.getString("education");
                                String university = jsonobject.getString("university");
                                String marks = jsonobject.getString("marks");
                                String passingYear = jsonobject.getString("passingYear");
                                String stream = jsonobject.getString("stream");
                                String grade = jsonobject.getString("grade");

                                empEducationList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails(userId,education,university,marks,passingYear,stream,grade));
                            }
                            empEducationDetailsModelLists.addAll(empEducationList);

                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this,
                            "Sorry! You are not connected to internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return empEducationDetailsModelLists;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> empEducationDetails) {
            super.onPostExecute(empEducationDetails);
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            empEducationDetailsAdapter=new EducationInfoAdapter(empEducationDetailsModelLists,EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(EmpEducationInfoFormActivity.this);
            empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            empEducationDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(empEducationDetailsAdapter);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        Context c;
        String urlAddress;


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**EducationInfoAdapter.java**

```
package abc.com.abcpos.Adapters;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod;
import abc.com.abcpos.Commons.Validations;
import abc.com.abcpos.Models.EmpEducationDetailsModel;
import abc.com.abcpos.R;
import abc.com.abcpos.forms.EmpEducationInfoFormActivity;

public class EducationInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    Context ctx;
    //private ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> sendEmpEducationDetailsList;

    Validations validationsObj =new Validations();

    public EducationInfoAdapter(ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> mEmpEducationDetailsList,Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mEmpEducationDetailsList = mEmpEducationDetailsList;
        //sendEmpEducationDetailsList=new ArrayList<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails>(mEmpEducationDetailsList.size());
    }

    public void addItem(){
        mEmpEducationDetailsList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails());
        notifyItemInserted(mEmpEducationDetailsList.size() - 1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_educationinfo, parent, false);
        return new EducationViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final EducationInfoAdapter.EducationViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        try{
            holder.nameOfBoardEditText.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getUniversity());
            holder.marksObtained.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getMarks());
            holder.stream.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getStream());
            holder.grade.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getGrade());
            holder.passingYear.setText(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getPassingYear());
            if (mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getEducation().toString() != null) {
                int spinnerPosition = holder.adapter.getPosition(mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).getEducation().toString());
                holder.educationSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
            }

            holder.nameOfBoardEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setUniversity(s.toString());
                }
            });
            holder.marksObtained.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setMarks(s.toString());
                }
            });
            holder.stream.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setStream(s.toString());
                }
            });
            holder.grade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setGrade(s.toString());
                }
            });
            holder.passingYear.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setPassingYear(s.toString());
                }
            });
            /*holder.educationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.get(position).setEducation(holder.educationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });*/
            if(ctx instanceof EmpEducationInfoFormActivity){
                ((EmpEducationInfoFormActivity)ctx).sendAllDataToServer(this.mEmpEducationDetailsList);
            }
           // holder.educationSpinner.setSelection(mEmpEducationDetailsList.indexOf());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEmpEducationDetailsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public List<EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails> retrieveEduData()
    {
        return mEmpEducationDetailsList;
    }

    public class EducationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText passingYear,marksObtained,stream,grade,nameOfBoardEditText;
        Spinner educationSpinner;
        String[]paths = {"Select Education", "Matriculation", "Higher Secondary", "Graduation","Post Graduation","Technical","Professional"};
        NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod numKeyBoard;

        TextInputLayout educationDetailsTextInputLayout,educationDetailsTextInputLayout1,educationDetailsTextInputLayout2,
                educationDetailsTextInputLayout3,educationDetailsTextInputLayout4,educationDetailsTextInputLayout5;

        Button addEmpEducation,delEmpEducation;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        public EducationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            passingYear=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.passingYear);
            marksObtained=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marksObtained);
            stream=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stream);
            grade=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grade);
            nameOfBoardEditText=(EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfBoardEditText);

            marksObtained.setTransformationMethod(numKeyBoard);

            educationDetailsTextInputLayout=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout1=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout1);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout2=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout2);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout3=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout3);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout4=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout4);
            educationDetailsTextInputLayout5=(TextInputLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationDetailsTextInputLayout5);

            educationSpinner=(Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.educationSpinner);

            addEmpEducation=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addEmpEducation);
            delEmpEducation=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delEmpEducation);

            passingYear.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    validationsObj.dateDialog(passingYear,(Activity) v.getContext(),event);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(itemView.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            educationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            delEmpEducation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), mEmpEducationDetailsList.size());
                }
            });
            addEmpEducation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mEmpEducationDetailsList.add(new EmpEducationDetailsModel.EmpEducationDetails());
                    notifyItemInserted(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), mEmpEducationDetailsList.size());
                }
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

**I have been through many links but could not find a good solution, so, please help me rather than downvoting the question!**

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, stick to the basics and nobody will downvote your question. An important part before posting a question on SO is to track down the issue to some degree, debug your code and try solving it on your own. You'll have problems getting help by just writing a hard-to-read block of text without paragraphs, copying over some of your classes and wait...

Comment: @Capricorn : Please don't downvote my question as this can't be explained in a better way tha this and i really need a solution to this.

Comment: In case you really can't explain the problem any better than SO is unfortunately not the best place for your case, maybe try services like https://www.codementor.io/. And for the record, downvote wasn't mine ;)

Comment: @jeevikadhillon can you post error log ?

Comment: An advice: start from the beginning. Add one `Card` with your data into the `RecyclerView` and figure out whether you get the data or not. If not, start debugging why this is happening. When you've fixed the first `Card`, then move on to multiple items. Right now you're making things very hard for yourself by adding a lot of extra stuff into the "equation". Start simple and start debugging from there.

Comment: @Darwind : I have tried doing a lot many things, but the problem is i want to get the data of all the cardviews present on the screen in the form of a list. The main issue is that i can add new card on (+) button click and i am not able to set user enterd values from card to mEmpEducationDetailsList